# Extracting text from a .txt file using fgetc and fgets

Tags: c

I'm writing code that extracts text from a .txt document and I'm having trouble with an `fgets()` call.

```
FILE *textFile
// Opening file and checking for error in opening
  textFile = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");

  if (textFile != NULL) {
    while((oneCharacter = fgetc(textFile)) != EOF) {
      if (inputFromUser == 1) {
        fgets(textLine, 80, textFile);
        length = strlen(textLine);
        printf("%s\n", textLine);
      }
```

When I print lineOfText it seems to omit the first letter of the textfile.  For example if the text I want to extract is:

```
StackOverflow is great!
```

It will print:

```
tackOverflow is great!
```

Am I missing anything with the syntax of the `fgets()` statement at all?

Comment: You have forgotten `ungetc(oneCharacter, textFile);` before the call to `fgets()` -- though it would be better just to use `while (fgets(textLine, sizeof(textLine), textFile) != NULL)` to control the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
while(fgets(textLine, 80, textFile) != NULL)
{

//  Code goes here
}
```

Since you are doing `fgetc()` you are already reading the first character from the file and the rest is read by your `fgets()` hence you are seeing that the first character is not there in your output